# Cannot read the property of "send" of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

Here is my code:

```
  let userdd =  bot.users.cache.get(args[1])
let messaged = args[2]
if(!messaged) return message.channel.send("Please specify a message!")
userdd.send(messaged)
```

But it has this errorr:
`Cannot read the property of "send" of undefined`

I tried other ways like:

```
  let userdd =  bot.users.fetch(args[1])
userdd.send(messaged)
```

and

```
  let userdd =  bot.users.fetch(args[1])
let person = bot.users.cache.get(userdd.id)
person.send(messaged)
```

Both give this error: `"Cannot send messages to this user"`
I tried the command on different people that have DM's on and have mutual servers to the bot but there is still that error.

Any Idea how to fix/is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to one user? It could be that the DM of that person is closed. In that case, you'll need a catch with a respons that the DM of that user is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, undefined has no property send. This means the userdd variable is undefined. You're right to try `bot.users.fetch(args[1])`, but it is a promise, so you must instead do it like:

```
bot.users.fetch(args[1]).then(person => {
    person.send(messaged);
});
```

A `.then` isn't necessary with `.cache.get()` because its pretty much instant, because it is cached, whereas `.fetch` takes quite a while, and you must wait for the user to actually be found before you can do anything with the user.